# How to restart a powershell instance?

Tags: powershell

What is the most efficient way to restart the PowerShell instance from within the PowerShell terminal?

Currently I do the following:

```
pwsh
```

This seems to start a new instance, but I am not sure whether this is restarting the processes or merely starting a new process.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? There's no such thing as "restarting a process" in Windows. Starting a new process and terminating the old one is the way to go.

Comment: With efficient, I mean what is most convenient way to relaunch the powershell (command or shortcut). To type "pwsh" seems just a bit odd.

Comment: You could write a function that invokes `pwsh -noexit -command "Get-Process -Id $PID |Stop-Process -Force"` so that the original process is automatically terminated if that's what you're after :)

Comment: is there no build-in way? For example I tried the shortcut CTRL+R, but this does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `pwsh` merely starts a new session in a *child* process of the current one, which lives on, and is returned to when you `exit` from the new one.
What you're probably looking for is to *replace* the current session with a new one.

---

- On ***Unix-like* platforms**, in PowerShell (Core) **v7.3+**, you can use **`exec`** (the built-in alias function<sup>[1]</sup> of the [`Switch-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Switch-Process) cmdlet) to *replace* the current process with a different one:

  ```
  # PS v7.3+, on Unix
  exec pwsh
  ```

  - In v7.2-, there's no simple solution, though you could consider use of (my) [`ttab`](https://github.com/mklement0/ttab) utility.
- On **Windows**, there is *no* direct equivalent:

  - In ***regular* console windows** (`conhost.exe`), as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, you can can achieve the same effect as follows:

    ```
    & (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path -NoExit -c "Stop-Process -Id $PID"
    ```
  - Unfortunately, this doesn't work in [*Windows Terminal*](https://aka.ms/windowsterminal), but you can **use its [CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments)**, `wt.exe`:

    ```
    wt.exe -w 0 -p $env:WT_PROFILE_ID
    ```

**Note**:

- The first two methods *inherit* the original session's *environment variables* and the current location (directory), but nothing else.
- The Windows Terminal method does *not*.

---

For convenience, you can **wrap these calls in a custom, cross-platform and cross-edition function, say `New-Session`**, which you can place in your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles); you **may also define a short *alias* for it, say `ns`**:

```
Set-Alias ns New-Session # define an alias

function New-Session {
  $envInheritanceNote = 'Note: Environment was INHERITED from previous session.'
  $envNonInheritanceNote = 'Note: Environment was NOT INHERITED from previous session.'
  if ($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') {
    if ($env:WT_PROFILE_ID) { # Windows Terminal
      # Windows Terminal: open a new tab in the current window using the same profile, then exit the current tab.
      # NOTE:
      #  * Does NOT inherit the calling shell's environment - only the environment of the master WT executable ('WindowsTerminal'),
      #    of which there is 1 per window. 
      #    (The tabs of a new window getting launched via wt.exe from a shell in a *regular console window*, for instance, DO inherit the caller's environment.)
      #  * The `Start-Sleep` call is to prevent the current tab
      #    from closing instantly, which, if it happens to be the only
      #    open tab, would close the Windows Terminal window altogether,
      #    *before* the newly launched tab opens.
      wt.exe -w 0 -p $env:WT_PROFILE_ID (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path -NoExit -Command "Write-Verbose -vb '$envNonInheritanceNote'"; Start-Sleep 1; exit
    }
    else { # regular console window (conhost.exe)
      & (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path -NoExit -c "Stop-Process -Id $PID; Write-Verbose -vb '$envInheritanceNote'"
    }
  }
  else {
    # Unix
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -gt 7 -or ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 7 -and $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor -ge 3)) {
      # PSv7.3+: use `exec` (built-in alias for `Switch-Process`) to replace the current shell process inside the current window.
      exec pwsh -noexit -c "Write-Verbose -vb '$envInheritanceNote'"
    }
    else { # PSv7.2-: not supported.
      throw "Not supported in PowerShell versions up to v7.2.x"
    }
  }
  exit
}
```

---

<sup>[1] `exec` is (now) a [*function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) rather than a regular [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases), for technical reasons: see [GitHub PR #18567](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/18567) for an explanation.</sup>